# JS variable (name) to PHP variable ($_POST["name"])

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Where I do the mistake?

HTML:

```
<p><?php echo($_POST['name']); ?></p>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var name = "John";

    function from_js_to_php()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {name: name}
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(from_js_to_php);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I would like to send JS variable `name` to PHP variable `$_POST["name"]`.

From `index.php` to `index.php`, so the same page.

I read and tried many options, but I either didn't understand or the option didn't work for me.

I am beginner and poor english speaker, so I am sorry for the frequent misunderstanding

Comment: This question is Too Broad, Unclear, and doesn't "make sense".  Why are you doing this?  What is failing?  Why are you POSTing using ajax back to the same page?  What is the goal?

Comment: If I load page, the variable in `<p>` is undefined. That is good, because the variable doesn't exist yet. But If I click on button with `name="submit"`, the variable is still undefined. Why? I sent the JS variable `name = "John"` to the POST variable `$_POST["name"]`. This is just a test. In finally, I will check the PHP variable with some string, like `$_POST["name"] == "John"`.

Comment: Do you _actually_ need to submit with ajax for your task?  Unless you have a specific reason for doing so, you are making the form submission harder than it needs to be.  From an ajax request, I imagine that you will want to have some sort of response that the POST was successful, but your code looks like it is a one-way transmission.

Comment: you'll need to process the server response after sending that `name`, catch it inside the success block of your ajax and then put it inside the paragraph tag

Comment: whats the meaning of doing it this way ? whats the propose ? because you can send your result throw Ajax anyway ???!!!! , using 2 php pages , include your php conditions and checkouts in the second page and the data you want to send throw ajax in the first page then return the result with `success : {}`.

Comment: Because I have JS prompt() and output is variable `name`. And I want to send this variable to PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is to send a POST variable to the current page, the only way I can think of is by using HTML form.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="hidden-form" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" value="John" name="name">
</form>
```

When this form is submitted, the page will be redirected to index.php with a POST request containing data `name`, which is what you want.

And you can use Javascript to control the form submission

```
document.getElementById("hidden-form").submit();
```

Comment: I know how it works. But I want send variable from JS, var name = prompt(); to $_POST["name"].

Comment: You can't set any php variable without a page reload. @J.Doe

Comment: $.ajax reloads my page, isn't it?

Comment: @J.Doe nope. you can try it

Comment: SO How I do it? What is my mistake in my ajax?

Comment: @J.Doe Based on what I know, it's not doable using ajax. That's why I suggested to you to use HTML form. Or, you can think about why do you even need to do something like this anyway.

Comment: OK, how I can give <form> and <input> to prompt() in JS. Because I have to use PROMPT().

Comment: @J.Doe No offense but you seems quite clueless about how the web actually works. I don't know how to explain it in a way that you would understand. I am unable to help.